# How can I query all my view designs looking for a particular string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, view

There are views created based on another system views in our SQL Server database. Since that another system is going to get replaced, I need to find the list of views that are built based on another system.

When I open the design of an existing view that is built on another system view, I can see another system server name.

So, I am looking for a query that queries all my view designs looking for a particular string 'Server Name', in this case.

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on what I understand you are looking for some string in the definition of your view, if that's the case you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) AS [ObjectName],
    o.type_desc AS [ObjectType]
FROM sys.objects AS o -- Will check all objects, inlcuding Views
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) LIKE '%cfs%' -- string in the definition
```

Note that I am checking against sys.objects instead of sys.views to look for the same keyword in other objects like procedures, tables, etc. you can change sys.objects to sys.views if you are only interested on views.

Comment: Hi Hector, Thank you for the response! I am not looking to find the string from the view names. When we open the view design, we see the server name and table name on which the view is built. I'd like to query that view design to look for a specific server name.

Comment: @Viknesh I changed the answer to query the definition and I also query objects instead of views just in case the server created other objects besides views.

Comment: Hi Hector, Thank you very much for your fast response! This has helped me. Appreciate your support!